# Protractor-tests executed with ‚directConnect: true’ throw ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, e2e-testing

When I run Protractor-tests using `directConnect: true` I get the error right at the moment when the browser-window pops up. The test executes smoothly and doesn't seem to be affected at all, though.

This error disappears when switching to Firefox, or when I run tests on `seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub` instead. (My Chrome version: 81)

I've found hints that it could be related to the Chrome-service not terminating properly at the end of the tests.

Terminal output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and solved it updating protractor and installing webdriver-manager:

```
npm i -D protractor webdriver-manager
```

In case you want to use Chrome, make sure the Chrome version matches the Chromium version downloaded by the webdriver-manager.